Significance of The Account
What is the significance of the account in blockchain network? You can't derive public key from it, only thing you can do is to say that JoeBloggsAccountName is very likely derived from a certain public key. I understand that blockchains also act as distributed databases and the actual public key can be retrieved from a dict<Account, PubKey> of some sort, still feels like an unneeded complication. Can anyone in the know comment on my point?

I don't know any system where the value of the account ("JoeBloggsAccountName") is "derived from a certain public key" for the meaning derived has in cryptography. And it's unclear what the question's "blockchain network" exactly is. I think the question would be best answered on a site dedicated to the blockchain (or cryptocurrency) considered.

by derived I mean all that double hashing and then taking first X number or characters, not the crypto derivation. I'm really trying to understand the value of having both Account and public Key in a situation when you need always pass both of them.

I very much doubt that "double hashing (the public key) and then taking first X number or characters" could give an account name such as "JoeBloggsAccountName". Perhaps you are referring to "vanity keys"? Again this is very system-dependent

it won't unless it's a vanity key you're right. The point is though what is the value of the account name when you'd always need to pass it along with the public key.

Are you asking why in a bitcoin context, there's the notion of "address" (not account) that is derived by hashing the public key? This is strictly bitcoin-specific, thus off-topic, and should be asked there.

No, sorry I'm asking a general question about address/account of any blockchain, they all seem to be produced of public key, and they seem to be useless without knowing the public key.

The formulation in the above comment is somewhat clearer. Thus it would be a good idea that you edit the question to remove/clarify what's incorrect (account name obtained by derivation/hashing), and replace "Account" with the better-known "Address". I still think there can't be a satisfactory answer from a cryptographic standpoint (beside the obvious: the address can be shorter than the full public key yet serve as a secure identifier), and the question is more appropriate for bitcoin-se.

it's not about bitcoin, nor about any specific blockchain. I'm asking why do we need account/address provided that it's useless on its own without public key. how can it be clearer?
